# Cottonwood Tree advice

Tags: tree-care

Location is Fountain, Colorado on the property is 2 Cottonwood trees approx 200 feet tall and they located in a trench that is about 5 feet deep. The trench has been filled now with dirt rocks and the tree is 5 feet deep in this back dill. Is this going to kill the tree? If so how quickly and what is the risk of it falling!?

Comment: Oh dear... could we please see a picture?  Is there any hope of excavating that trench back out?  How wide was the trench?  The tree's roots and trunk will not like being buried.

Comment: Also, how wide was the trench before it was filled? Was the trench formed by fill being placed around the tree sometime in the past couple of years?

Comment: Those are some very tall cottonwoods. Hard to imagine as i look at 100 ft loblolly pines in my yard.

Answer (score 3):

For most tree species, feeder roots extend from the trunk to about 1.5 times the width of a tree's crown. Feeder roots are the roots that typically absorb the most water and pull oxygen from the air. For a 200 foot tall cottonwood, I'm estimating that the crown is about 60-70 feet in diameter/30-35 foot radius, which means that the feeder roots extend about 50 feet from the trunk.

If the trees germinated in the trench, then the feeder roots are at the level of the trench's soil and possibly uphill from it. This was working well for the trees. If the trench was formed by in-fill, then the feeder roots are buried five feet deep. If this occurred recently, then the trees may already be dying due to suffocation, as there can be no oxygen exchange at that depth, as well as possibly from lack of water (this depends on how recently the trench was created).

In any case, no tree likes to have its crown buried by five feet of fill. This will almost certainly kill the two trees over the next several years or longer.

Answer (score 2):

Might take a few years, but it's a death sentence.

https://extension.okstate.edu/fact-sheets/site-disturbance-and-tree-decline.html

Potentially could have been mitigated before filling the trench with an array of pipes along the old soil level, but that's probably too little, too late, and too difficult to do after the fact.

200 foot tall dead trees less than 200 feet from the house are a considerable hazard for falling or breaking.